# Handler not found error in aws lambda while using a simple rest api call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to execute the following code in AWS Lambda.

```
const https = require('https')

var options = {
  host: 'http://url',
  port: 3000,
  path: '/resource?id=foo&bar=baz',
  method: 'POST'
};

https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
}).end();
```

But i am getting the following error.

> ```
>   "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
> ```

How do i solve this?

Comment: I would start by reading the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use JavaScript to build a Lambda function, check the ***AWS SDK for JavaScript Developer Guide for SDK Version 3***. There are quite a few step by step tutorials that will answer this question and teach you how to perform this use case.

Start with this:

[Invoke a Lambda function from a browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/cross_LambdaForBrowser_javascript_topic.html)

Make sure that you always read the AWS SDK Guiide (in addition to the Service Guide) when using Lambda and the AWS SDK for JavaScript:

[Getting started with the AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started.html)